# How to modify color of label in IBOutletCollection

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, iboutletcollection

My question is - how do I modify any color like backgroundColor, textColor of each label in

```
IBOutletCollection(UILabel) NSArray *smallLabels
```

I tried everything to access each element of the array using the index. In my case I have 10 labels, each label have its number from 1 to 10.

All I've done so far is connecting each label to the IBOutletCollection, but I have a clue that I have never initialized my array in code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the -(void)awakeFromNib method invoke?

Comment: When you use an array as IBOutletCollection, it is automatically init and filled with views. You should be able to access it in viewDidLoad like all other outlets.

Comment: Astoria,
Yes it does, but I haven't put any code in there. Why ?

Comment: @Imotep , I do access each element using the method objectAtIndex, but I can't modify the color. My code looks like:
    [[_smallLabels objectAtIndex:1] backgroundColor] = [UIColor greenColor];
It gives an error. I still have no idea.

Comment: The error was: Expression is not assignable.
Anyways I've found the solution below. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this

```
for (UILabel *myLabel in self.smallLabels) 
{
  myLabel. backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
}
```

Comment: All my labels are green now. Thanks a lot !

Comment: To make things clear, the error you got with [[_smallLabels objectAtIndex:1] backgroundColor] is that when you get an object from an NSArray it's an id. As an id object doesn't have the backgroundColor property, compiler raise an error. By using a foreach instead of a classic for, you tell the compiler that objects your are expecting are UILabels, which does have the backgroundColor property. You could also solve the problem like this: [((UILabel*)[_smallLabels objectAtIndex:1]) backgroundColor]

Comment: As you tell IB this is a collection of UILabel, it will only allow you to add labels to this collection, so you don't have to check the class.

Answer (score 0):

Alright. I've been thinking whole day and finnaly I found the solution that worked out best for me.
As I said I need to access each element , not the whole array.

Code:

```
[[_smallLabels objectAtIndex:1] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
```